# Grant Power BI Service Admin role to AAD Service Principal into O365 tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

I'm setting up a Power BI auditing solution using an Azure Automation Account and the [Power BI Powershell Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-role). In order to access PBI audit logs Power BI Services Admin role is needed. 
This role can be granted to O365 Tenant users [via Microsoft 365 admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-role) or via the [Azure Portal using directory built-in roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfnUq.png).

This seems not that straightforward to me when I try to grant the given role to the AAD App Registration used to authorize the Power shell script in order to run programmatically. My question is: which is the best way to perform this operation on a service principal? I found a lot of documentation, but most of the time it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Hi Fabio, may I know if the answer matches your requirements ?

Comment: Hi Hury, sorry I didn't have the chance to test your solution (unfortunately I'm not the O365 tenant global admin). Hope to try in the next week. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I misunderstand your requirement, please let me know.

You mentioned we can add the role to service principal via Microsoft 365 admin center or via the Azure Portal using directory built-in roles. And then you want to know which is the best way to do this operation to allow you run the powershell script programmatically. So I think we can just use the powershell command which is shown in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-role#assign-users-to-the-admin-role-with-powershell) you provided above, or you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) to know more about this command.

```
Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId <the power bi admin role id> -RefObjectId <your service principal(or user) objectId>
```

Assign the role by this command, you can run it programmatically and without do the assign role operation in web page. I think this is the best way to do it.